# Get all values in a field

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse 
I have a "Post" class with fields.
Post class have some field, and one of it is "user" linked with "User" class

I want query Post class and get all the users in the response.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
// How to get all user in the post class
```

Is there another way like..

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
let usersQuery = PFUser.query()
usersQuery.whereKey("SELF", matchesKey: "user", inQuery: query)
```

But I know there is no SELF keyword

Objective C is also fine

Comment: How have you linked your post class with user class..? have you used PFRelation? Please elaborate.

Comment: @TejvanshSinghChhabra yes I linked it the type is "link" not relation in the parse database

Comment: Do you want to fetch those posts which contain a specific user in its user field, right?

Comment: @TejvanshSinghChhabra I want to filter the Post with (e.g. Date) and get all users that have those posts.

Comment: `I want query Post class and get all the users in the response.` can you explain what that means?

Comment: @RaVeN the Post class has field named "user", it's linked with User class. It means the post belong to that user. I want to get all users from the post class.

Answer (score 0):

Given [this page in the Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects), it should look something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
query.findObjectsInBackground() { posts, error in
  if (!error) {
    for post in posts {
      let user = post["user"]
      println("User: \(user)")
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Parse you use a PFQuery to query the database..

In a callback (asynchronusly) you get a PFObject or an array of PFObjects.

How to do this is written in [their guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects)

Here's a little example:
You can get all properties/fields whatever by calling the array function on the PFObject.

```
var pfObject = PFObject()
pfObject["yourcolumn"] as? String //Whatever you want
```

In your case a PFUser would be the solution

```
pfObject["yourusercolumn"] as? PFUser
```

To query you use a [PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)

Asynchronusly (preffered):

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        println(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

Synchronusly:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
var objects = query.findObjects()
for object in objects {
  // Do whatever you want with your pfobject
}
```

Asynchronus queries are more likely because they don't run on the GUI thread what makes your app way more faster (on the UI).